# Error : NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [name] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't resolve this error, here is my datas :

Schemas :

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.algorithm (
    algorithm_id serial NOT NULL,
    company_spec varchar(255) NULL,
    description varchar(255) NULL,
    docker_image_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    input_spec varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    output_spec varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT algorithm_pkey PRIMARY KEY (algorithm_id)
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.pi (
    pi_id serial NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(255) NULL,
    pi_type_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pi_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pi_id),
    CONSTRAINT fko2uqm9q0pxhoq3lg48favc2s8 FOREIGN KEY (pi_type_id) REFERENCES pi_type(pi_type_id)
);
```

Datas :

```sql
INSERT INTO algorithm (algorithm_id, name, description, input_spec, output_spec, company_spec, docker_image_name) VALUES
(1, 'fake algorithm 1', 'fake algorithm 1 description', 'python pi_scalar.py', 'scalar', NULL, 'pi_python_docker_image'),
(2, 'fake algorithm 2', 'fake algorithm 2 description', 'python pi_timeseries.py', 'timeseries', NULL, 'pi_python_docker_image'),
(3, 'csic''s algorithm', 'csic''s algorithm description', './pi_csic.m;.csv;anthropometry.yaml', 'scalar;scalar;scalar;scalar;scalar;scalar', '', 'pi_csic_docker_image');
```

```sql
INSERT INTO pi (pi_id, name, pi_type_id) VALUES
(1, 'fake_scalar_1', 1),
(2, 'fake_time_series_1', 2),
(4, 'step_length_left', 3),
(5, 'step_time_right', 4),
(6, 'step_time_left', 4),
(7, 'stride_time_right', 5),
(8, 'stride_time_left', 5),
(3, 'step_length_right', 3);
```

And my query code :

```java
public interface IExperimentRepository  extends JpaRepository<Experiment, Integer>{

    @Query(value ="SELECT a.name, e.pi_id, p.name, g.aggregation_type_name, e.score "
            + "FROM experiment_pi_aggregation_score e "
            + "JOIN algorithm a "
            + "ON e.algorithm_id=a.algorithm_id "
            + "JOIN pi p ON e.pi_id=p.pi_id "
            + "JOIN aggregation_type g ON e.aggregation_type_id=g.aggregation_type_id "
            + "WHERE e.experiment_id = :id "
            + "ORDER BY e.pi_id ASC, g.aggregation_type_name ASC", nativeQuery = true)  
    public List<Object> findScores(
            @Param("id") Integer id
            ); 
      }
```

I have already changed the long column names with alias but still same error..

I am using Postgres 11.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `jquery`?

Comment: I've removed the jQuery tag. Please add the specific DBMS tag to the question, eg `MSSQL`

Comment: Maybe because there are two columns in the result named `name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the aliases in the query:

```
public interface IExperimentRepository  extends JpaRepository<Experiment, Integer>{

@Query(value ="SELECT a.name as algorithm_name, e.pi_id, p.name as pi_name, g.aggregation_type_name, e.score "
        + "FROM experiment_pi_aggregation_score e "
        + "JOIN algorithm a "
        + "ON e.algorithm_id=a.algorithm_id "
        + "JOIN pi p ON e.pi_id=p.pi_id "
        + "JOIN aggregation_type g ON e.aggregation_type_id=g.aggregation_type_id "
        + "WHERE e.experiment_id = :id "
        + "ORDER BY e.pi_id ASC, g.aggregation_type_name ASC", nativeQuery = true)  
public List<Object> findScores(
        @Param("id") Integer id
        ); 
  }
```